# Access data from object instead of saving it using saveAsTextFile

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

In the below code snippet, saveAsTxtFile would write it to a file in comma separated format.
Instead i would like to have the data in-memory as an object and manipulate it.

```
val logFile = "/tmp/master.txt"
val positive = "/tmp/positive.txt"
val negative = "/tmp/negative.txt"

val sc = new JavaSparkContext("local[4]", "Twitter Analyzer", "/siva/spark-1.1.0/",Array("target/scala-2.10/Simple-assembly-0.1.0.jar"))

val twitterFeed = sc.textFile(logFile).cache()

  val value = iterator.next()
  val numAs =  twitterFeed.filter((i: String) => i.contains(value))

  numAs.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/output/positive/" + value)
```

So the question is, how do i consume the values from the variable numAs?
say the file contents are

```
a,b,1,2
c,d,3,4
```

i would like to do some job specific to a,b and c,d alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numAs` is already an in-memory RDD. You have two options:

1. continue working on the contents of the `numAs` RDD, using the RDD [operations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations)
2. 'collect' the contents of the RDD into an array and operate on it:

   val content = numAs.collect

   mOp(content)

**Option #1** will keep taking advantage of the distributed Spark infrastructure and should be the way to go for large datasets.

**Option #2** will collect the RDD data at the driver as an array. The data must fit in the driver memory. The resulting array is just a normal JVM array with contents of the same type as the source RDD and you can use all the supported Scala functions on it.

Comment: If i wanted to go with option 1, how would i read the contents of numAs, what specific operation should be used? An example would be immensely helpful.

Comment: I think @massg refers to map operations such as mapPartitions or flatMap. Check (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations") to obtain more information about these operations.

Comment: @Siva on the link above [http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations](operations) you can see the transformations and actions that can be performed on an RDD. What would you like to do with `numAs`?

Comment: The numAs variable would ideally contain the list of csv values read from a text file, I want to iterate the entire list to get particular values in the list of csv. say call a function with 2 values taken from csv for the entire list.

Comment: @Siva   if the number of elements you are preserving is fairly low (you mention 2 items), I'd just do: `val data=numAs.collect   val result=operate(data)` where `operate` does whatever you need to do with that array of values.